# Different results when encrypting data using AES-128-CBC in C# and Php

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I need to send encrypted data from an application in C# to an external web service written in PHP (it is a 3rd party web application that I do not have control over it). I have been provided with the following code snippet with respect to the encryption logic used in the PHP application:

```
    $data = 'data to be sent';
    $base64data = base64_encode($data);     
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CBC"; 
    $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering); 
    $options = 0; 
    $encryption_iv = '1234567891234567'; 
    $encryption_key = md5('123456789'); 
    $encryptedData= base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($base64data, $ciphering, 
                                                  $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv));
```

I have written the following implementation in C#, however the result of the encryption is different than the one generated from the PHP code.

```
            string data = "data to be sent";
            string base64data = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

            // Encryption key is MD5 hash of value: '123456789'
            MD5 hasher = MD5.Create();
            byte[] HashValue = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123456789"));
            string encryptionKey = "";
            foreach (byte b in HashValue)
            {
                encryptionKey += b.ToString("x2");
            }
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);

            byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567891234567");

            RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.Key = keyBytes;
            aes.IV = iv;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt);

            swEncrypt.Write(base64data);

            swEncrypt.Close();
            csEncrypt.Close();
            aes.Clear();
            aes.Clear();
            byte[] encryptedData = msEncrypt.ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted data: {Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData)}");
```

Note that I have also used the the AesManaged class in .NET and the related classes in BouncyCastle.Crypto library to do the encryption in C# (in case that I might have missed something in my implementation). In all cases the generated result in C# (same of course no matter which library used in .NET) is different than the one generated from the PHP code. Can someone provide any information about what might be the issue?

Comment: Why are you converting `HashValue` into hex, then getting the bytes of that hex representation to use as the encryption key? I don't see you doing that in the PHP. What happens if you just use `HashValue` as the key? (Or is that not long enough for a key? Perhaps PHP is just padding with 0s?)

Comment: I am pretty sure encryption keys are different. So, regardless of which one is _correct_ they cannot result in same cypher text.

Comment: The computation of the encryption key in C# is implemented this way so as to end up with the same value for the encryption key as the one generated by the PHP md5 call. md5('123456789') in PHP gives: '25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b' which is the same value the encryptionKey variable is getting when executing the above C# code. So, even if I execute the above code samples having set the $encryption_key and encryptionKey variables in PHP and C# respectively to the value '25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b', the generated results are still different.

Comment: In the PHP code a hex encoded key is applied, you should use the binary data: `$encryption_key = md5('123456789', true)`. Also, it's Base64 encoded twice, this should be removed, e.g.: `$options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`. Furthermore, in the C# code `HashValue` must be used _directly_ as key (see Jon Skeets's comment). Then the ciphertexts are the same. By the way, the Base64 encoding of the plaintext before encryption is not necessary and a static IV is insecure.

Comment: Now that you have changed your post and explained (way too late) that the PHP code is the reference, you have to implement the bugs in the PHP code in the C# code. Use the first 16 bytes of `HashValue` as key and Base64 encode the ciphertext twice. That way the ciphertexts are also the same.

Comment: @Topaco, sorry I forgot to mention that the PHP code was provided to me as it is. I am not familiar to PHP and the PHP web application I need to call from my code (c#) is from a 3rd party vendor. However I did the changes that you suggested and now the generated results are the same, so I guess I would have to take it to the support team of the Vendor. Thanks a lot.